# Add an item in the "move to" contextual menu

Tags: context-menu

I am trying to add an item when I right click on a file or folder. I want to add "moved to shred" under "Move To"

I do not want to delete the file or move it to trash. I have a folder where I put all my personal files so I can shred them using:

`shred -n30 filename`

I like to do this manually to make sure I do not destroy important files or files i put there my mistake.

I try the nautilus action but it is not very user friendly.

How can I add a new option under the "move to" group?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 but it will be nice to know if 14.04 supports it too since I am planning to migrate soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BleachBit** to achieve this,

Install BleachBit On your ubuntu machine

```
sudo apt-get install bleachbit
```

Download the latest version using the following command:

```
wget -c http://katana.oooninja.com/bleachbit/sf/bleachbit_0.9.5_all_ubuntu1210.deb
```

Now install BleachBit and its dependencies using the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i bleachbit_0.9.5_all_ubuntu1210.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
```

you can open BleachBit either from Terminal or from Menu

**Also you can add a right click secure delete action for files and folders with the following steps**

Make sure you have **bcwipe** installed from the repo. Create a **wipefiles.desktop** file and paste this code into it.

```
[Desktop Action delete]
Exec=bcwipe -rf -mt
Icon=bleachbit
Name=Delete File

[Desktop Entry]
Actions=delete;
Name=wipefolders
Name[en_US]=wipefolders
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=all/allfiles,inode/directory,KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
```

As root (obviously) put it in **/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus**

Log out and back in. There should now be a secure Delete File option in the Actions menu when you right click on a file or folder.

Hope this helps!

Comment: cannot access /usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus: No such file or directory. Also I am already using shred, I do not need another one that do the same thing. I am using Unity, not KDE ....

Comment: @Erik - that is because the answer seems related to the KDE (Kubuntu environment)